# How do I do permissions in asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net-identity

I am trying to use asp.net identity and would like my roles to have permissions. Users could then have a set of roles which dictate what permissions they have

I cant find any permission related objects on asp.net identity - it this achievable using asp.net identity?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, not out of the box. You will need to "roll your own".

If you read [this article on one of Microsoft's own websites](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs) which talks about Creating and Managing Roles in ASP.NET you'll notice that there is no discussion of permissions. The ASP.NET roles framework is very plain Jane.

Rolling your own is a bit of a learning curve but the journey will be exhilarating! The way that I (and others) did it is I created a new class which implements [IPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then added a new custom called HasPermission(PermissionId requestedPermissionId) which does for permissions what "IsInRole()" does for roles.

Something like this:

```
public bool HasPermission(PermissionId requestedPermissionId) {

// "PermissionsHeld" is of type IEnumerable<PermissionId>

// If PermissionsHeld is null then the user doesn't hold any permissions
if(this.PermissionsHeld == null) {
    return false;
}

// Returns true when PermissionsHeld contains "requestedPermissionId"
return this.PermissionsHeld.FirstOrDefault(ph => ph.PermissionId == requestedPermissionId) != null;
}
```

You can learn more about integrating your custom IPrincipal implementation by reading these articles: [Custom Authentication and Authorization](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/G54G220114-Custom-Authentication-and-Authorization-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html) and [Implementing Custom Authentication for ASP.NET](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1216/implementing-custom-authentication-for-aspnet). There are many other articles like those two; I picked those two because at a glance they seemed to cover everything that I ended up implementing in my project.

Good luck! I had a lot of fun building my own implementation of the same.

Comment: Here's a related blog post: [A better way to handle role permissions in ASP.NET Identity – IsInRole vs. HasPermission](http://odetodata.com/2015/05/a-better-way-to-handle-role-permissions-in-asp-net-identity-isinrole-vs-haspermission/)